# How to resolve transitive dependency conflict in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have encountered my first transitive dependency conflict in a Gradle build, and am not sure which of the many documented methods best applies to my case.

I have a root project which is responsible for running functional tests on multiple child Gradle Plugin Project, but has no other code besides the test cases. I am using the [Manual Classpath Injection](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html#sub:test-kit-classpath-injection) method to get the child projects in the test classpath.

```
// Write the plugin's classpath to a file to share with the tests
task pluginUnderTestMetadata {
    def outputDir = file("${buildDir}/pluginUnderTestMetadata")
    def runtimeClasspath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    outputs.dir(outputDir)
        .withPropertyName("outputDir")

        inputs.files(runtimeClasspath)
                .withPropertyName("runtimeClasspath")
                .withNormalizer(ClasspathNormalizer)


    doLast {
        outputDir.mkdirs()
        file("$outputDir/plugin-classpath.txt").text = runtimeClasspath.join("\n")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation localGroovy(),
            gradleApi(),
            project(':waweb.site.plugin'),
            project(':waweb.site.plugin.js'),
            project(':waweb.site.plugin.sass'),
            project(':waweb.site.plugin.template'),
            project(':waweb.site.plugin.war')

    testRuntimeOnly files(pluginUnderTestMetadata)
    testImplementation gradleTestKit(),
            "junit:junit:${JUNIT_VER}",
            "org.assertj:assertj-core:${ASSERTJ_VER}",
            "org.hamcrest:hamcrest:${HAMCREST_VER}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:${SERENITY_VER}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:${SERENITY_VER}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber:${SERENITY_CUCUMBER_VER}"
}
```

This all works great until I add `closure-compiler` as a dependency to one of the subprojects, which results in a runtime error:

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.Gson.&lt;init&gt;(Lcom/google/gson/internal/Excluder;Lcom/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy;Ljava/util/Map;ZZZZZZZLcom/google/gson/LongSerializationPolicy;Ljava/lang/String;IILjava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;)V
at net.thucydides.core.reports.json.gson.GsonJSONConverter.&lt;init&gt;(GsonJSONConverter.java:38)
while locating net.thucydides.core.reports.json.gson.GsonJSONConverter
at net.thucydides.core.guice.ThucydidesModule.configure(ThucydidesModule.java:56)
while locating net.thucydides.core.reports.json.JSONConverter
at net.serenitybdd.core.history.FileSystemTestOutcomeSummaryRecorder.&lt;init&gt;(FileSystemTestOutcomeSummaryRecorder.java:42)
while locating net.serenitybdd.core.history.FileSystemTestOutcomeSummaryRecorder
at net.thucydides.core.guice.ThucydidesModule.configure(ThucydidesModule.java:72)
while locating net.serenitybdd.core.history.TestOutcomeSummaryRecorder
    for the 2nd parameter of net.serenitybdd.core.history.HistoricalFlagProvider.&lt;init&gt;(HistoricalFlagProvider.java:28)
while locating net.serenitybdd.core.history.HistoricalFlagProvider
at net.thucydides.core.guice.ThucydidesModule.configure(ThucydidesModule.java:71)
while locating net.thucydides.core.model.flags.FlagProvider
```

I believe this is due to confliting gson versions as shown in the dependency report below. It would be ideal if I could somehow seperate these classpaths so they could both use thier internal transitive dependencies without issue, but I'm not sure how to go about it given my unusual setup, or if this is even possible. Do I need to define some constraints, use a platform, decouple my builds, or something else entirely?

Any insight you can give in addition to a working solution will be greatly appreciated.

*Abridged Dependency Report*

```
runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- project :waweb.site.plugin
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.8
[SNIP GROOVY DEPS...]
+--- project :waweb.site.plugin.js
|    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.8 (*)
|    +--- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:v20191111
|    |    +--- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-externs:v20191111
|    |    +--- args4j:args4j:2.0.26
|    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
|    |    |    +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.1.3 -> 2.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1
|    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14
|    |    +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 3.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:1.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.jsinterop:base:1.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:1.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.elemental2:elemental2-core:1.0.0-RC1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:1.0.2
|    |    |    \--- com.google.jsinterop:base:1.0.0-RC1 -> 1.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.re2j:re2j:1.3
|    \--- project :waweb.site.plugin (*)

testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- project :waweb.site.plugin
+--- project :waweb.site.plugin.js
+--- project :waweb.site.plugin.sass
+--- project :waweb.site.plugin.template
+--- project :waweb.site.plugin.war
+--- junit:junit:4.12
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- org.assertj:assertj-core:3.14.0
+--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2
+--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:2.0.90
|    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.1
|    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.10.1
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.0-jre
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|    |    +--- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.0.0
|    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.1.3
|    |    +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1
|    |    \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14
|    +--- com.google.inject:guice:4.2.2
|    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.2
|    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
|    +--- org.objenesis:objenesis:3.0.1
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26
|    +--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
|    +--- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:2.4.0
|    |    +--- info.cukes:cucumber-html:0.2.6
|    |    +--- io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.6
|    |    +--- io.cucumber:gherkin:5.0.0
|    |    \--- io.cucumber:tag-expressions:1.1.1
|    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    +--- io.vavr:vavr:0.9.0
|    |    \--- io.vavr:vavr-match:0.9.0
|    +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12
|    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1
|    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0.1
|    +--- javax.activation:activation:1.1.1
|    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0
|    +--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-report-resources:2.0.90
|    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.1
|    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.10.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.0-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.inject:guice:4.2.2 (*)
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.2
|    |    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
|    |    +--- org.objenesis:objenesis:3.0.1
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26
|    |    +--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
|    |    +--- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:2.4.0 (*)
|    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    +--- io.vavr:vavr:0.9.0 (*)
|    |    +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12
|    |    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1
|    |    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0.1
|    |    +--- javax.activation:activation:1.1.1
|    |    \--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0
|    +--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-model:2.0.90
|    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.1
|    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.10.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.0-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.inject:guice:4.2.2 (*)
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.2
|    |    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
|    |    +--- org.objenesis:objenesis:3.0.1
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26
|    |    +--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
|    |    +--- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:2.4.0 (*)
|    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    +--- io.vavr:vavr:0.9.0 (*)
|    |    +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12
|    |    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1
|    |    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0.1
|    |    +--- javax.activation:activation:1.1.1
|    |    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0
|    |    +--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-report-resources:2.0.90 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1
|    |    +--- commons-net:commons-net:3.6
|    |    +--- com.typesafe:config:1.3.1
|    |    +--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3
|    |    +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.7
|    |    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
|    |    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.6
|    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.6 -> 1.7
|    |    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:1.8.3
|    |    +--- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.0
|    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4
|    |    +--- org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:4.2
|    |    +--- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.9
|    |    |    +--- xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.1
|    |    |    \--- xpp3:xpp3_min:1.1.4c
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.5
|    |    +--- net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12
|    |    +--- org.awaitility:awaitility:4.0.1
|    |    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.1 -> 2.2
|    |    +--- org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj:1.5.6
|    |    +--- org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.28
|    |    +--- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-all:0.34.30
[SNIP FLEXMARK DEPS...]
|    |    \--- es.nitaur.markdown:txtmark:0.16
|    +--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-reports:2.0.90
|    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.1
|    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.10.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.0-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.inject:guice:4.2.2 (*)
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.2
|    |    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
|    |    +--- org.objenesis:objenesis:3.0.1
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26
|    |    +--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
|    |    +--- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:2.4.0 (*)
|    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    +--- io.vavr:vavr:0.9.0 (*)
|    |    +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12
|    |    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1
|    |    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0.1
|    |    +--- javax.activation:activation:1.1.1
|    |    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0
|    |    +--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-model:2.0.90 (*)
|    |    \--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-stats:2.0.90
|    |         +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.1
|    |         +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.10.1
|    |         +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.0-jre (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.inject:guice:4.2.2 (*)
|    |         +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.2
|    |         +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
|    |         +--- org.objenesis:objenesis:3.0.1
|    |         +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26
|    |         +--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
|    |         +--- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:2.4.0 (*)
|    |         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |         +--- io.vavr:vavr:0.9.0 (*)
|    |         +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12
|    |         +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1
|    |         +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0.1
|    |         +--- javax.activation:activation:1.1.1
|    |         +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0
|    |         +--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-model:2.0.90 (*)
|    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
|    |              +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    |              \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.6
|    +--- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:3.141.59
[SNIP SELENIUM DEPS]
|    +--- com.paulhammant:ngwebdriver:1.1.4
|    +--- com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.4.4
|    +--- org.seleniumhq.selenium:htmlunit-driver:2.36.0
|    |    \--- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.36.0
|    |         +--- xalan:xalan:2.7.2
|    |         |    \--- xalan:serializer:2.7.2
|    |         |         \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04 -> 1.4.01
|    |         +--- org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.7
|    |         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.9
|    |         |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9
|    |         |         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.11
|    |         |         \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |         +--- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:2.36.0
|    |         +--- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-htmlunit:2.36.0
|    |         |    \--- xerces:xercesImpl:2.12.0
|    |         |         \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
|    |         +--- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-cssparser:1.5.0
|    |         +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.6
|    |         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |         +--- commons-net:commons-net:3.6
|    |         +--- org.brotli:dec:0.1.2
|    |         \--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:9.4.20.v20190813
|    |              +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:9.4.20.v20190813
|    |              |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.4.20.v20190813
|    |              |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.20.v20190813
|    |              |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.20.v20190813
|    |              |    |         \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.20.v20190813
|    |              |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.20.v20190813 (*)
|    |              +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:9.4.20.v20190813
|    |              |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.20.v20190813
|    |              +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.20.v20190813
|    |              +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.20.v20190813 (*)
|    |              \--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:9.4.20.v20190813
|    |                   +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:9.4.20.v20190813
|    |                   +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.20.v20190813
|    |                   \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.20.v20190813 (*)
|    +--- io.appium:java-client:7.2.0
|    |    +--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6
|    |    |    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.2
|    |    |    |    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1 -> 3.2.2
|    |    |    +--- commons-digester:commons-digester:1.8.1
|    |    |    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
|    |    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.4
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.1.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.2.RELEASE
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.1.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.1.2.RELEASE
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.5
|    +--- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.0
|    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:1.8.3
|    +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.7
|    +--- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.9 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1
|    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
|    +--- org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.28
|    +--- net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.36.0 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5 -> 4.5.9 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.5 -> 4.5.9 (*)
|    +--- org.fluentlenium:fluentlenium-core:0.10.2
|    +--- com.jhlabs:filters:2.0.235
|    +--- org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj:1.5.6
|    +--- org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:4.2
|    +--- javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4
|    +--- org.glassfish.web:javax.el:2.2.4
|    |    \--- javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4
|    +--- xalan:xalan:2.7.2 (*)
|    +--- xalan:serializer:2.7.2 (*)
|    +--- org.awaitility:awaitility:4.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.typesafe:config:1.3.1
|    +--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3
|    +--- com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1
|    \--- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-all:0.34.30 (*)
+--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:2.0.90
|    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.1
|    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.10.1
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.0-jre (*)
|    +--- com.google.inject:guice:4.2.2 (*)
|    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.2
|    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
|    +--- org.objenesis:objenesis:3.0.1
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26
|    +--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
|    +--- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:2.4.0 (*)
|    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    +--- io.vavr:vavr:0.9.0 (*)
|    +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12
|    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1
|    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0.1
|    +--- javax.activation:activation:1.1.1
|    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0
|    +--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-model:2.0.90 (*)
|    +--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:2.0.90 (*)
|    +--- junit:junit:4.12 (*)
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
\--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber:1.9.49
    +--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:2.0.90 (*)
    +--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:2.0.90
    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.1
    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.10.1
    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.0-jre (*)
    |    +--- com.google.inject:guice:4.2.2 (*)
    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.2
    |    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
    |    +--- org.objenesis:objenesis:3.0.1
    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26
    |    +--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
    |    +--- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:2.4.0 (*)
    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
    |    +--- io.vavr:vavr:0.9.0 (*)
    |    +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12
    |    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1
    |    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0.1
    |    +--- javax.activation:activation:1.1.1
    |    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0
    |    \--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:2.0.90 (*)
    +--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-webdriver:2.0.90
    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.1
    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.10.1
    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.0-jre (*)
    |    +--- com.google.inject:guice:4.2.2 (*)
    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.2
    |    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
    |    +--- org.objenesis:objenesis:3.0.1
    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26
    |    +--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
    |    +--- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:2.4.0 (*)
    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
    |    +--- io.vavr:vavr:0.9.0 (*)
    |    +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12
    |    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1
    |    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0.1
    |    +--- javax.activation:activation:1.1.1
    |    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0
    |    +--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:2.0.90 (*)
    |    \--- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:2.0.90 (*)
    +--- io.cucumber:cucumber-java:2.4.0
    |    \--- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:2.4.0 (*)
    +--- io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:2.4.0
    |    \--- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:2.4.0 (*)
    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.5
    +--- junit:junit:4.12 (*)
    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4
```

Comment: Note: I only have the projects on the implementation classpath so I can grab them in the pluginUnderTestMetadata, so perhaps the ideal solution is to somehow generate this text file without explicitly adding the projects as dependencies. The plugin-classpath.txt is correct as is, but the test runner fails to initialize when these projects are listed as direct dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I really should wait 24 hours before I post because the answer always pops into my head randomly when I'm thinking of something else.

**Solution:**

```
configurations {
    pluginsUnderTest
}

task pluginUnderTestMetadata {
    def outputDir = file("${buildDir}/pluginUnderTestMetadata")
    def runtimeClasspath = configurations.pluginsUnderTest

    outputs.dir(outputDir)
        .withPropertyName("outputDir")

    inputs.files(runtimeClasspath)
            .withPropertyName("runtimeClasspath")
            .withNormalizer(ClasspathNormalizer)


    doLast {
        outputDir.mkdirs()
        file("$outputDir/plugin-classpath.txt").text = runtimeClasspath.join("\n")
    }
}

dependencies {
    pluginsUnderTest localGroovy(),
            gradleApi(),
            project(':waweb.site.plugin'),
            project(':waweb.site.plugin.js'),
            project(':waweb.site.plugin.sass'),
            project(':waweb.site.plugin.template'),
            project(':waweb.site.plugin.war')

    testRuntimeOnly files(pluginUnderTestMetadata)
    testImplementation gradleTestKit(),
            "junit:junit:${JUNIT_VER}",
            "org.assertj:assertj-core:${ASSERTJ_VER}",
            "org.hamcrest:hamcrest:${HAMCREST_VER}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:${SERENITY_VER}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:${SERENITY_VER}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber:${SERENITY_CUCUMBER_VER}"
}
```

Hopefully this will at least save anyone some time if they wish to set up functional tests on various configurations of plugin projects.